# Android Image SetVisibility not work

Tags: android

I create a file in the layout folder eclipse and folder name is `grid_single.xml` and into the

```
grid_single.xml
```

i write this xml file:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/grid_image"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:visibility="gone"
     >
```

and up image show into the gridView i want set visibilty to true and show the image,but when i write this code:

```
final ImageView img4=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
img4.setVisibility(1);
```

but when program run the program is crash!

Comment: where you write this piece of code?

Comment: You should directly reference fields via the static variables instead of hardcoding them.  Such as img4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); Visible is actually a hardcoded 0.  So, not sure what 1 would be referencing.

Comment: Could you please add the stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `View.VISIBLE` instead of using `1`.

This should work (I added also a null check if you did something wrong on the layout inflation):

```
if(img4 != null) {
    img4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Just for reference (you should not use this):

- [`View.GONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) has the value 8
- [`View.VISIBLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE) has the value 0 and
- [`View.INVISIBLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) has the value 4

Comment: i write and this error 08-27 11:16:13.001: E/AndroidRuntime(2483):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

Comment: You need to add some more lines that allone does not help. Edit this to your question please.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to visible your Image in your adapter,if is it true ,you should do like this:

in getView() method:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View rowView = inflater
            .inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null, true);
final ImageView img4=(ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
img4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not *exactly* sure what you're asking, but it looks like you are trying to programmatically make an XML defined View visible.  If that is the case, you want to do `img4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` rather than set to 1, as the constant for visibility is not equal to 1 (see [the View class's documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#VISIBLE)).